# jQuery .ajax .load .get x(h)tml related error ("mismatched tag, expected: </br>")

Tags: jquery, ajax, parsing, get, load

My problem is actually simple, but nevertheless I need someone with in-depth-knowledge here. Imagine the following simple task: Load / parse some external html data into an element of a current html file.

Let's say, this is the content of the external file, that we want to retrieve:

```
<div id="element">
  <img src="test.jpg"><br>
  lorem ipsum
</div>
```

And this is the code using jQuery .load

```
$("#div_in_mother_html").load("external.html #element");
```

Works like charme.
But looking in the console, I see the following **ERRORS**:

```
1. mismatched tag. Expected: <br />
2. mismatched tag. Expected: <img />
```

**Why is that?**

Well, pretty obviously, **.load** is a shorthand for **.ajax** in jquery, which is, as far as I understand, a cross-browser **XMLHttpRequest**. This may cause mismatched tag problemss, for HTML-tags do not close, unlike XHTML:

HTML - `<img src="test.jpg"><br>`
XHTML - `<img src="test.jpg" /><br />`


**Next try**

Alright I say, it must be possible to parse not XML but HTML. And yes, the documentation of jQuery says so, too. I switch from .load to the more advanced .ajax and tried setting the data-type manually:

```
$.ajax({ type:'GET', url:'ajax.txt', contentType: "text/plain; charset=utf-8", 
 dataType:'text', success:function(data){ 
    $('#div_in_mother_html').html(data); } 
});
```

And again, it works...but the same silent errors show up in the console.


*error seen in firefox 32 browser console in local environment.*

Comment: Is the file served with the approriate `text/html` mime type.

Comment: Sounds like the html document that you are loading has syntax errors. Validate the document and fix the bad mark up. http://validator.w3.org/ Code should be `<img src="test.jpg"/><br/>`

Comment: I appreciate every help, but please do not answer by blind guessing.
at adeneo: Yes, it is <meta charset="UTF-8"> at epascarello: Please read about the problem at hand! The file has no markup-errors, it is valid HTML 5. The "error" results from the XMLrequest handling the file as XHTML, and not HTML.

Comment: You asked this question [a year ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18024105/jquery-load-returns-error-junk-after-document-element), and deleted that old one a few minutes after posting this one. As for the "blind guess"; that would be because you aren't giving enough information to do anything more than blindly guess.

Comment: Hi Andrew, true, I asked that question a year ago. Since then I found out a lot myself, so I was able to rephrase this question and lead the problem to the XMLHttpRequest. I did not want to raise an old topic, unless I could give an appropriate answer myself. I am sorry, if that was the wrong way. Topic: I updated the question with demonstration files. It really is that simple: It's not a question about faulty syntax or markup or whatsoever: It is straight forward -> How (if) can jquery .ajax parse HTML instead of XML/XHTML?

Comment: @Knecker your assumptions are wrong. XMLHttpRequest is NOT defaulted to xml or in any way restricted to XML. In your case, your html is being parsed as html, not xml, unless your server is responding with the text/xml content-type.

Comment: Another possible cause would be if you're using $.ajaxSetup and setting the default dataType to xml.

Comment: @KevinB: Thanks for your comment! Now I am completely puzzled. I am working offline and as you can see in the question above, I also tried setting up the .ajax manually to content- and data-type:text. (Also tried data-type:html, but with no sucess). I have uploaded some demo files, maybe that helps in evaluation? Thank you very much so far.

Comment: as a general rule i don't download anything from questions on SO. primarily because if the question requires it to be solved, the question doesn't have enough information included.

Comment: also, i would suggest not doing this testing on the local filesystem, as that will have odd results in some browsers when working with ajax. At least setup a localhost webserver

Comment: @KevinB: Right you are, deleted the files. Couldn't really set it up as fiddle though. And by the way, after one year of searching, you just gave the solution in a side notice: The "problem" is my noobish stupidity...it was working locally without a webserver. I still don't know why exactly that makes a difference, but obiviously it does. Please post your comment as an answer, so that I may mark it as such? Thousand regards

Comment: An alternative to jsfiddle that allows for easier ajax testing is plunker.

Comment: I'm confused then. what was the actual problem? that when requesting from the filesystem it assumes xml? or what

Comment: @KevinB: Well, I guess it did. It parsed clearly as XML. Once moved to a webserver, the errors where gone. Can't really explain myself why, but your instincts were right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My guess would be that when you request it when working from the filesystem, it is for some reason parsing it as xml. You really shouldn't ever test ajax from the filesystem anyway since  the filesystem will never return all the same headers that you would get from a real server. Fix would be to setup a local webserver running on localhost.

Comment: So simple and yet so intriguing. Your guess is absolutely correct, that was the problem. Thank you very much.